# If i want to print any one element only from an array .. any of the array. what would be the code then?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = {
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
};
```

If i want to print any one element only from an array .. any of the array. what would be the code then ?

suppose i want to print "Type: chocolate". Then how would i write the code for it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A very vague question. Please be specific.

Comment: which array? both? and in which style? please add some code and the wanted result.

Comment: Do you want to just directly access a property? `a.topping[2].type` then. Do you want to iterate the `a` object and print all `type`-keys?

And yes, what have you already tried? :)

Comment: this is a json data stored in var a. I want to write a code to fetch "type": "Chocolate".  Want to fetch from this json object and print that. This is the basic thing that i want to do from both of the arrays. :)

Comment: Kindly help as I am all new to this. Will something like this come for printing "type: chocolate"   for(var=0, 1= a.batter.length; i<1; i++) {
                              var name = a.batter[1].type ;

Answer (score 0):

you can write it like :

```
for(var i=0;i<a.batters.batter.length;i++){
   console.log(a.batters.batter[i].type)
}
```

if you wan't to print chocolate only you may access the array without loop over it like

```
var name = a.batters.batter[1].type;
```

Comment: thanks but i just want to print Chocolate not all... will it be the exact one? for(var=0, 1= a.batter.length; i<1; i++) {
var name = a.batters.batter[1].type ;